# Python bus error destroy python environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-machine, bus-error

I am running python 3.7 using anaconda installation on ubuntu 16 virtual machine. Due to some extensive pandas merges my machine runes out the memory what is causing bus error (why not memory exception).

But after that crash, my python installation is corrupted. It looks like random python files (like site.py) are modified.

The problem occurs each time in a different way. I have also tried to change the mode during the execution of anaconda directory to 000 and files also looked corrupted. Any help or root cause?

One of the failure:

> Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 579, in 
>       main()
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 566, in main
>       known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 349, in addsitepackages
>       addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 207, in addsitedir
>       addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 163, in addpackage
>       for n, line in enumerate(f):
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Hello, please describe what you are trying to do and share your code.

Comment: Your error related with some decoding process, it might occur because path description with special chars, single slash instead of double, empty space(s), etc. You should share the code too.

Comment: Guys to code have literally 3 lines - pandas merge in loop. After few minutes it hits bus error. And after that some random python files are corrupted.